# Таким образом, на этих противопоставленных друг другу примерах, писатель подчёркивает

Tags: пунктуация

Будет ли *противопоставленных друг другу* обособляться или нет?

Comment: А зачем вторая запятая? И как можно **на** примерах что-то подчёркивать?

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста: 
1.
Таким образом, на этих противопоставленных друг другу примерах, писатель подчёркивает....

2.Таким образом, на этих, противопоставленных друг другу, примерах, писатель подчёркивает....

Comment: Разве причастный оборот *противопоставленнных друг другу* не будет обособляться

Comment: У вас определяемое слово после причастия, какое обособление?

Answer (score 3):

В исходном предложении, конечно, одна запятая лишняя. Другие запятые без особой необходимости ставить не нужно:

*Таким образом, на этих противопоставленных друг другу примерах писатель подчёркивает...*

Если хочется выделить пояснительную конструкцию, тогда можно использовать и запятые, и тире, и скобки:

*Таким образом, на этих (противопоставленных друг другу) примерах писатель подчёркивает...*

Если же есть возможность переставить слова, то получится причастный оборот после определяемого слова:

*Таким образом, на этих примерах, противопоставленных друг другу, писатель подчёркивает...*